# Non-uniform axis in matplotlib histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, bins

I would like to plot a histogram with a non-uniform x-axis using Matplotlib.
For example, consider the following histogram:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
values = [0.68, 0.28, 0.31, 0.5, 0.25, 0.5, 0.002, 0.13, 0.002, 0.2, 0.3, 0.45,
      0.56, 0.53, 0.001, 0.44, 0.008, 0.26, 0., 0.37, 0.03, 0.002, 0.19, 0.18,
      0.04, 0.31, 0.006, 0.6, 0.19, 0.3, 0., 0.46, 0.2, 0.004, 0.06, 0.]
plt.hist(values)
plt.show()
```

[image: Demo histogram]

The first bin has high density, so I would like to zoom in there.

Ideally, I would like to change the values in the x-axis to something like `[0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1]`, keeping the bin widths constant within the graph (but not numerically, of course). Is there an easy way to achieve this?
Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from André is nice, but the bin widths are not constant. Working with a log2 x-axis suits what I was looking for. I use [np.logspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) to make the bin widths constant in the graph.

That's what I ended up doing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
values = [0.68, 0.28, 0.31, 0.5, 0.25, 0.5, 0.002, 0.13, 0.002, 0.2, 0.3, 0.45,
        0.56, 0.53, 0.001, 0.44, 0.008, 0.26, 0., 0.37, 0.03, 0.002, 0.19, 0.18,
        0.04, 0.31, 0.006, 0.6, 0.19, 0.3, 0., 0.46, 0.2, 0.004, 0.06, 0.]
bins = np.logspace(-10, 1, 20, base=2)
bins[0]=0
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.hist(values, bins=bins)
ax.set_xscale('log', basex=2)
ax.set_xlim(2**-10, 1)
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram log2]

Answer (score 1):

Using bins will solve the problems. The bins are the values to which you assign the values for example 0.28 will be assigned to bin 0.3. The code below provides you an example of using bins:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
values = [0.68, 0.28, 0.31, 0.5, 0.25, 0.5, 0.002, 0.13, 0.002, 0.2, 0.3, 0.45,
  0.56, 0.53, 0.001, 0.44, 0.008, 0.26, 0., 0.37, 0.03, 0.002, 0.19, 0.18,
  0.04, 0.31, 0.006, 0.6, 0.19, 0.3, 0., 0.46, 0.2, 0.004, 0.06, 0.]
plt.hist(values, bins=[0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1])
plt.show()
```

To plot it in a more suitable way, it can be handy to convert the x axis into a logaritmic scale:

```
plt.hist(values, bins=[0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1], log=True)
```

changes the log scale on the y axis. Adding the following line to your code will make a logaritmic x axis for your histogram:

```
plt.xscale('log')
```

Comment: Thank you André! It isn't exactly what I was looking for because the bin widths are not constant in the resulting graph, but your solution inspired me.